# Getting 404 errors only on some devices

Tags: html, node.js, express, heroku

I recently purchased a domain and created a Heroku web app ([www.musicforthemood.com](http://www.musicforthemood.com)), but when trying to access from certain laptops and phones, I get an "Site is under development" or "Error 404: Page not found". Sometimes it seems to work when I type in [www.musicforthemood.com](http://www.musicforthemood.com), and sometimes it works only without the www (so, musicforthemood.com). It seems very inconsistent and the error seems to be happening randomly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @user4642212 I have tried that on all devices, but even if the page works, 5 minutes later it may not work again. very strange

Comment: I would try flushing the DNS cache (on a Windows machine, it's "ipconfig /flushdns"), but that doesn't explain everything you're seeing.  If you just updated the site recently, I'd suspect that it's being propagated around their servers (in which case it should resolve itself in time).

Comment: @AvinavDhakal You should collect more info about the error and give a good description about it, it helps to easily identify the problem